# not able to load data from firebase database on firebase recycler view adapter in new activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**this is mainactivity code**

```
 package com.example.sharma.digimenu;


        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

        import com.example.sharma.digimenu.Common.Common;
        import com.example.sharma.digimenu.Model.User;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

        import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSignUpDialog();
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSignInDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showSignUpDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN UP");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to sign up");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View signup_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_signup, null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        final MaterialEditText edtName = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final MaterialEditText edtPhone = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);

        dialog.setView(signup_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN UP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter  password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                                user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                                user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                                user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                                users.child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Register Successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
});
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
    private void showSignInDialog() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN IN");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to sign in");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View signin_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_signin, null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = signin_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = signin_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        dialog.setView(signin_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter  password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    public User user;

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));
                        Common.currentUser = user;
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**this is home.java**

```
 package com.example.sharma.digimenu;


        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

        import com.example.sharma.digimenu.Common.Common;
        import com.example.sharma.digimenu.Model.User;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

        import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSignUpDialog();
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSignInDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showSignUpDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN UP");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to sign up");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View signup_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_signup, null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        final MaterialEditText edtName = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final MaterialEditText edtPhone = signup_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);

        dialog.setView(signup_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN UP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter  password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                                user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                                user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                                user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                                users.child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Register Successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
});
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
    private void showSignInDialog() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN IN");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to sign in");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View signin_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_signin, null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = signin_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = signin_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        dialog.setView(signin_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter  password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    public User user;

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));
                        Common.currentUser = user;
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Menuviewholder.java file**

```
    package com.example.sharma.digimenu.ViewHolder;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sharma.digimenu.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.sharma.digimenu.R;

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView txtMenuName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        txtMenuName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
         imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
    }
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
```

**Activity_home.xml file second acitivy**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/background_light"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**data is not viewing in new activity from firebase**
**this is my logcat at running**

```
06-24 22:06:08.063 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
06-24 22:06:08.063 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@1da9cec4
06-24 22:06:08.069 466-1271/com.example.sharma.digimenu W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
06-24 22:06:08.074 466-1271/com.example.sharma.digimenu I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
06-24 22:06:10.323 466-585/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( ythvbsqhYURD3NrN5LlNtXZsDMC3 ).
06-24 22:06:10.324 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
06-24 22:06:10.325 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
06-24 22:06:10.328 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.sharma.digimenu time:25840099
06-24 22:06:10.337 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 25151
06-24 22:06:10.338 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Connecting to remote service
06-24 22:06:10.340 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Activity paused, time: 72826503
06-24 22:06:10.344 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=25151, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2677346009036919789}]
06-24 22:06:10.347 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: onActivityCreated
06-24 22:06:10.372 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
06-24 22:06:10.474 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-2677346009036919789, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Home, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2677346009036919788}]
06-24 22:06:10.489 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 72826637
06-24 22:06:10.544 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-24 22:06:10.544 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
06-24 22:06:10.617 466-466/com.example.sharma.digimenu I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d97ab3e time:25840388
06-24 22:06:15.575 466-521/com.example.sharma.digimenu V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

**Images screenshot of new activity**

***MainActivity Page*** :

[image: [][1]]

***Home activity where the list of food items with RecyclerView*** :

[image]

**how can the data be binded from firebase database to view list food items using firebase recycler view adapter**

Comment: Please post home activity. You posted mainactivity twice.

Comment: Welcome. Please read about [Minimum Viable Examples], then `edit` your question to conform to Stack Overflow guidelines.  Doing so improve your chances in getting an answer, and is also the first step in debugging.  SO users are volunteers.  Removing unnecessary code makes easy for users to see your issue,  makes the code and your question more attractive to delve into, and signals personal effort. 
It saves Every User from individually trimming the fat to figure out your Q.  It also may help you gain clarity.  Not doing so may punt your question toward removal as being too broad, or unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need an adapter. Official firebase library doesn't have any adapter class but there is very useful library called firebaseui.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android